# Max, SelectMany, with possible no responses

Tags: c#, linq, max

I receive the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

on

```
MainFields.ForEach(Field => Field.Size = Math.Max(FilesObject.SelectMany(x => x.Fields).Where(y => y.Name == Field.Name).Select(m => m.Size).Max(), Field.Size));
```

My MainFields object needs to be updated based on all the fields in the FilesObject. The root cause of the issue is at times the MainFields Name doesn't exist in the FilesObject, which is necessary.

I could break this into a loop and add some logic checks, but I was hoping that there's a way in Linq to avoid that.

Comment: use default if empty`.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()`

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is such a way - put `DefaultIfEmpty()` before calling `Max()`:

```
Math.Max(FilesObject.SelectMany(x => x.Fields)
  .Where(y => y.Name == Field.Name).Select(m => m.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()
```

`DefaultIfEmpty` will return enumerable with one default element if collection contains no elements, so then `Max()` will return this element (because it's the only one) for empty collection (of course use appropriate default value, I used 0 just for example).

Comment: That's it! Thank you.